Kubernetes agent pod is running but not able communicate back to Jenkins
I'm running my jenkins within the EKS cluster. I have installed the latest version of kubernetes plugin. I have configured the cloud and the test connection is working as expected. When I tried to run the pipeline, I see a pod is created within the cluster. But in jenkins it is saying pod is offline. I have tried many times, still the same issue.
Created Pod: kubernetes jenkins-1/apk-generator-masmovil-314-3vcqv-4kcdq-9psdr     
Still waiting to schedule task 
'apk-generator-masmovil-314-3vcqv-4kcdq-0v3p8’ is offline

And I don't see any logs in the created pod.
kubectl logs apk-generator-masmovil-314-3vcqv-4kcdq-0v3p8 -n jenkins-1
Defaulted container "agent" out of: agent, jnlp

How to resolve this?

I made few changes which eventually resolved my issue.

In the configuration, for jenkins url I have given http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080. I thought this is the default url. Turned out, the pattern is http://jenkins-service.namepace.svc.cluster.local:8080. So in my case, its http://jenkins.jenkins-1.svc.cluster.local:8080 as my namespace is jenkins-1
I have removed the jenkins tunnel URL. Even though, I don't think that will make any difference.
In pod template, I have removed the default values in command to run(sleep) and argument to pass to the command (9999999).
In the environment variables of the container, I have passed the following. JENKINS_TUNNEL: jenkins-agent.jenkins-1.svc.cluster.local:50000 and JENKINS_URL: http://jenkins.jenkins-1.svc.cluster.local:8080

The below are the links I was referring

https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-agents-kubernetes
https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/7360

